# Cant Figure out this c# reference

Tags: c#

I was using the "this" keyword in my default constructor, below is the code in the class movie

```
namespace Movie_List
{ enum GenreType { Action, War, Drama, Thriller }; 
 class Movie 
 { 
    //Data Members 
    private String _title; 
    private int _rating; 
    private GenreType _type;

    //Properties


    public GenreType GenType
    {
        get { return _type; }
        set { _type = value; }
    }
    public String Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { _title = value; }
    }


    public int Rating
    {
        get { return _rating; }
        set { _rating = value; }
    }




    public Movie()
        : this("Jaws", GenreType.Action, 4) { } 

    public Movie(String title, GenreType type, int rating ) //working ctor
    {
        Title = title;
        GenType = type;
        Rating = rating;

    }

    public override string ToString()
    {           
        return String.Format(" {0} Genre : {1},  Rating: {2:d} Stars. ", Title, GenType, Rating);
    }

}
```

I wanted to read in from a text file so i used this code in the MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    string lineIn = "";
    string[] filmarray;
    using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader("filmlist.txt"))
    {
        while ((lineIn = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            filmarray = lineIn.Split(new char[] { ',' });
            moviecollection.Add(new Movie()

            {
                Title = filmarray[0],
                GenType = (GenreType)Enum.Parse(typeof(GenreType), filmarray[1]),
                Rating = Convert.ToInt32(filmarray[2]),
            });
            lstFilms.ItemsSource = moviecollection;
        }


    }
}
```

I dont need this bit of code now

```
: this("Jaws", GenreType.Action, 4)
```

But when i deleted it, the genre action and rating 0 stars still prints.

Why is this Happening does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `enum` and `int` are always initialized with default value of 0.

It's not like `string` - if you don't initialize it will equal `null`. If you want to emulate this behavior for `int`, you can always try using `int?` type.

To get more details on this subject take a look at [Default Values Table (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

When you have this initialization:

```
Movie movie = new Movie();
```

the empty constructor

```
public Movie() : this("Jaws", GenreType.Action, 4) { }
```

calls the overloaded constructor which have several parameters:

```
public Movie(String title, GenreType type, int rating) { ... }
```

When you delete this line: `this("Jaws", GenreType.Action, 4) { }`, what is happening now is that you are only calling the empty constructor which does nothing at all.

So when you call

```
int ratingValue = movie.Rating;
```

the default value of integer which is `zero` is returned because you did set anything on it.

**UPDATE**

a simple `if` (*maybe, if I understand what you mean*)

Assuming `Rating` should be greater than zero.

```
public override string ToString()
{     
    if (Rating == 0)
    {
        return String.Format("{0}", Title);
    }
    else
    {
        return String.Format(" {0} Genre : {1},  Rating: {2:d} Stars. ", Title, GenType, Rating);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand better now what is going on but how do I stop  Genre : Action,  Rating: 0 Stars from being printed out?

Comment: what do you mean by `stop Genre : Action, Rating: 0 Stars from being printed out`? *confused*